# Integrate pages

Tags: html

I need to integrate a page from another site on to my own. What are the ways to do it ,,

apart from `<object>` and `<iframe>`? What if the site  does not provide an RSS feed?

Comment: you have asked 10 questions, and only appear to have accepted one of them. You are not rewarding those who give up their time to answer your questions with some recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the site doesn't provide some API to access its contents and you don't want to use iframes your only solution is to use site scraping: have a server side script that will send an HTTP request to the remote site, fetch the HTML, parse the HTML and pass it to your views. Obviously this could raise some copyright concerns so you should make sure that you have read the remote site policy about this. It is also extremely fragile and it might break at the moment the remote site changes its structure because you will be relying on HTML parsing.

Comment: IS the RSS symbol only way to find if a site is RSS enabled?

Comment: @Kutu, the RSS symbol indicates that the remote site exposes its contents through RSS. But if this symbol is not present it doesn't mean that the site doesn't provide an API to access its contents. For example google has no symbols and yet it provides an extensive API. So you might contact the site owner if you have doubts.